# using populate to display username instead of id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running Expressjs with mongoosejs I made the connection between the collections CustomerId as below:

```
.
.
/**
* Customer Schema
*/
var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    id : Number,
    name: String,
    joined: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    city: String
});

mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
.
.
/**
* Order Schema
*/
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    id : Number,
    products: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    total: Number,
    comments: String,
    customerId: {type: Number, ref: 'Customer'}
});

mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);
.
.
exports.customerOrders = function (req, res) {
   return Order.find({customerId: req.params.customerId}, function (err, orders) {
       Order.populate(orders, {path: 'customerId', model: 'Order'}, function (err, orders) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json(orders);
        } else {
            return res.send(err);
        }
    });
});
};
```

the above code generate the following error:

```
{
  message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" at path "_id"",
  name: "CastError",
  type: "ObjectId",
  value: 1,
  path: "_id"
}
```

the relation between objects is `id` no `_id`

Please help me to use the populate method in the right way.

Thanx,

Comment: Hi @ya, deleted what I put, on a second look, I think what you actualy need is on the line `customerId: {type: Number, ref: 'Customer'}` to be `customerId: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer'}` where `mongoose` is the name you gave eg - `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Comment: No, i'm not referencing the ObjectId, I'm referencing custom Number field so the Objects are connected with numbers

Comment: Might be worth a look - stackoverflow.com/questions/15771470/mongoose-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose's `populate` functionality only supports using the `_id` field to find the related doc in the referenced collection.

So you can't use another field like `id` and you'd need to change `customerId` to be:

```
customerId: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Customer'}
```

in `OrderSchema` and then populate it with the `_id` value of the customer instead.

Comment: I managed to reference the related objects with id field but without populate(), I wanted from the first to use populate() to display the customer.name in place of customer.id but still link the related objects with id. Any idea to do that?